# Having problems in running Latex in atom text-editor in Debian-based linux

Tags: linux, atom

I have downloaded Texlive and latex and language-latex package in atom. 
However,when I save the .tex file, the LaTex log at the bottom shown that

```
TeXification failed!Builder executable 'latexmk' not found
latex.texPath
as configured:
when resolved:
/usr/texbin:/Library/Tex/texbin:/....
Make sure latex.texPath is configured correctly either adjust it via `the setting view or directly in your config.cson file`
```

I think the problem is about configuration, but how can I config it?

Moreover, there is another warming
`Parsing of log files failed.`
Did I miss downloading anything?

I am still new to Linux, can anyone help?

Comment: What exactly did you install? Have you installed LaTeX? Which one? The one from debian? Then you probably also need to separately install `latexmk` from Debian. (Debian has a tendency to split latex into many small Debian pieces and leave it to the user to figure out what they need). Might be best to get the compilation working from the command line first and then move to Atom

Comment: is latexmk  installed ? if not, you should install it from your debian favorite package manager

Comment: Debian has a separate package `latexmk`, see for example https://packages.debian.org/buster/latexmk for Debian 10.

Comment: I installed texlive, does it include latexmk? i am using ubuntu should I download the package from Debian 10?

Comment: The `texlive` package does not contain `latexmk`. There is (also for Ubuntu) a separate package called `latexmk` that you need to install. When you enter `sudo apt install latexmk` in Ubuntu, then the package for your version of Ubuntu will be installed.

Comment: i downloaded it, but the problem still exists.I have reopened atom a couple of times and restate my computer as well. The location of the latexmk is in /usr/bin/latexmk.

Comment: Is the error message still the same (executable 'latexmk' not found)? If yes, did you try to set the path as suggested by the last line in the error (adjust via the settings menu or in the `config.cson` file)? If no, what is the new error message?

Comment: I have this exact same problem, and have put some good hours trying to fix it.  Only clue I have is that I have upgraded my distro (mint 19.3 --> Mint 20).  I had to re-download Atom and reinstall the packages.  Of this particular LaTeX package, I looked very closely at the settings of a machine that is running (but didn't have the OS upgraded or Atom re-installed).  Really out of ideas now.

Answer (score 1):

I use Linux Mint 20 and facing a similar problem. I found out that this problem occurs on the Flatpak version of Atom, which is the default Atom package in the Software Manager.

I solved this problem by removing the Flatpak version of Atom and installing the deb version of Atom from the Atom official page (https://atom.io/download/deb). The deb version of Atom works well with the latex package.